# Controlling distance between lines broken manually

Tags: line-spacing

It's fairly easy to control the length between lines separated by an empty line using `\setlength{\parskip}`. I'm wondering if there's a similar command that dictates the default/global length of the manual line break provided by `\\`.

Comment: `\\[length]` will do.  However, ``\\`` should not be used in general text, except in unusual circumstances.

Comment: I'm familiar with that option. My question is regarding whether there's a way to globally alter the default length. I've edited the original question to reflect this.

Comment: One of the issues is that ``\\`` is modified often by various environments, etc.  So, even if you globally redefine it with a new break distance, it won't apply in all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\\` is an in-paragraph line break so the spacing is `\baselineskip` You can change `\baselineskip` but it will change all linespacing in the paragraph for automatic and for forced breaks.

It would of course be possible to change the definition of `\\` to do anything else

```
\def\\{hello}
```

for example, but it is best not to. If the markup is intended to show something other than a normal break within a paragraph (but just chosen by the author rather than by the system) then `\\` is the wrong markup.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an optional line break gap using `\\[<len>]`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

This is \\
a line that is \\[5pt]
farther apart than \\
others.

\end{document}
```

For a more general spread of lines, consider looking into the [`setspace` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace).

---

Perhaps the following might also be of interest:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pargap}[1][0pt]{%
  \par
  \ifdim#1>\z@
    \vspace{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\parskip+#1}
    \noindent
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is a line that is

\pargap[5pt]

farther apart than others.

\end{document}
```